# Изменить функцию

Tags: python

Функция находит день недели для данного дня месяца и данного дня недели для первого дня месяца. Например, если заданный день месяца = 7 и день недели для первого дня месяца = 3 (среда), то функция должна вернуть 2 (что означает вторник).
Что поменять в функции, чтобы возвращало не 0, а 7?

```
def get_day_week (day, starting_dotw):
    some_variable = (day % 7 + starting_dotw - 1) % 7
    return some_variable
```

Comment: (day + starting_dotw - 2) % 7 + 1

Comment: Зачем вы затираете ваш вопрос? Да ещё и на прошлые вопросы ответы не принимаете... Не надо так.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_variable = (some_variable + 1 - 2) % 7 + 1
```

Comment: То есть у вас теперь понедельник = 0, вторник = 1 и так далее?

Comment: нет, понедельник так и остается 1, воскресение 7. внимательней к формуле присмотритесь

Comment: Каким образом (1 + 7) % 8 должно так и остаться 1 ? Вы пробовали ваш код запустить, или только присматривались к нему?

Comment: что-то в нем забыл, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Допишите перед строчкой с return:

```
some_variable = some_variable or 7
```

Comment: логические функции с числами не желательны

Comment: @eri Что значит "не желательны" если это общепринятый способ?

Comment: то что он общепринятый я знаю, но читаемость не очень - заставляет думать и приводить типы к boolen в голове. В этом случе inline if читабельней.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_day_week(day, starting_dotw):
        return (starting_dotw + day - 2) % 7 + 1
```

Comment: лучше пояснить почему и как вы пришли к такому решению